# How to show "Login In failed.Please try again" message in angular when API returns the response?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular6

I have simple login screen in Angular as:

[image]

When the username and password is entered, it successfully hits the /login URL and if it is correct it goes to the userdashboard or admindashboard and when username and password is incorrect it shows me /403 forbidden page.

The output in console comes like:

[image]

However I want to show "Login Failed Please enter correct Username and Password Message" but the API is returning the response in the form

```
@PostMapping(value="/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> login(@RequestBody User user,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            Authentication authentication= authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()));
            final JwtUser userDetails=(JwtUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            final String token=jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
            response.setHeader("Token",token);
            return new ResponseEntity<UserDTO>(new UserDTO(userDetails.getUser(), token),HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedExcpetion(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

If login is success it returns user object neither it returns the message "Bad Credentials".

And in my Angular I have tried to check the error condition and want to apply the message strategy but it is not printing in `console.log()` if the login is failed but if the login is success then response is printed in `console.log()`.

```
loginUser(user:any){
    this.userService.loginUser(user).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log("test");
        if (response) {
            console.log(response.token);
            if (response.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify(response));
                if(response.user.role==='ADMIN') {
                    this.router.navigate(['/admindashboard']);
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/userdashboard']);
                }
            } else {
                console.log(response.error.message);
            }    
        }
    })    
  }
```

userservice.ts

```
loginUser(user:any):Observable<any>{
    const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",user,{headers:headers});
}
```

Comment: why are you adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the **request** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response that you are getting goes into the error block in the front end so declare a boolean variable as showErrormessage as false and write the following code in HTML:

```
  <div *ngIf="showErrorMessage">
    <h1>Invalid username and password Please try again</h1>
  </div>
```

And in ts file write this

```
//Declare this variable
showErrorMessage=false;

loginUser(user:any){
    showErrorMessage = false;
    this.userService.loginUser(user).subscribe(
        (response) => {
            console.log("test");
            if (response) {
                console.log(response.token);
                if (response.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
                    if (response.user.role === 'ADMIN') {
                        this.router.navigate(['/admindashboard']);
                    } else {
                        this.router.navigate(['/userdashboard']);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("No Token");
                }
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            showErrorMessage = true;
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the error of the observable. Subscribing an observable takes an object with up to 3 properties, which itself take a function as value, the `next` handles good data, the `error` handles errors and the `complete` is a final call e.g.

```
const subscription = this.data.subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.info('complete'),
})
```

So you need to add an error handler to catch the condition you are talking about.

Reference:

- https://angular.io/guide/observables
- https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Comment: Passing multiple arguments is deprecated since RxJS 6.4: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments. Rather, an object with `next`, `error`, `complete` properties with function values should be passed as argument.

Comment: @DavidWolf feel free to update my answer in line with the current specification - its been a while since I used it, so no confident I can update it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will get your response in the error function of observable. So, just catch the error.

> **Here I have updated the code.**

```
loginUser(user:any){
    this.userService.loginUser(user).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("test");
        if(response){
        console.log(response.token);
            if(response.token){
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify(response));
                if(response.user.role==='ADMIN'){
                    this.router.navigate(['/admindashboard']);
                }else{
                    this.router.navigate(['/userdashboard']);
                }
            }
         else{
        console.log(response.error.message);
      }   
        }            
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Login Failed'); // handle login failed here. 
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a second function in subscribe to catch the error.

```
  loginUser(user:any){
    this.userService.loginUser(user).subscribe(
      (response) => {
      console.log("test");
        if(response){
        console.log(response.token);
            if(response.token){
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify(response));
                if(response.user.role==='ADMIN'){
                    this.router.navigate(['/admindashboard']);
                }else{
                    this.router.navigate(['/userdashboard']);
                }
            }else{
              console.log("No Token");
            }
        } 
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
```